# vb.net Linq statement to find duplicates using fuzzy searching

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable containing:

- ID as Integer = Primary Key.
- Name as String
- OtherFields ....

I have a function that can find duplicate names in the table

```
Private Function DuplicateComputerNames() As String
    Dim ret As String = $"Duplicate Computer Names found in Table Computer.{vbCrLf}"
    Dim computerTable As DataTable
    computerTable = ComputerTableAdapter.GetData
    Dim duplicates = computerTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("Name")) _
        .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key)
    For Each d In duplicates
        ret = $"{ret}{vbTab}{d}{vbCrLf}"
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

This works perfectly.

Now sometimes the name has a prepend of "(POOL)"  i.e. "Laptop-55 (POOL)"
I need a function that will find duplicates of just the Laptop-55 part.
i.e. If there is a Laptop-55 and a Laptop-55 (POOL)

I thought this code would do the job, but apparently not.

```
Private Function PoolComputerNames() As String
    Dim ret As String = $"Possible Duplicate Computer Names found in Table Computer.{vbCrLf}"
    Dim computerTable As DataTable
    computerTable = ComputerTableAdapter.GetData
    Dim duplicates = computerTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("Name")) _
        .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key.Split("("c)(0).Trim())
    For Each d In duplicates
        ret = $"{ret}{vbTab}{d}{vbCrLf}"
    Next
    Return ret
End Function
```

Hoping that someone can point in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: That couldn't possibly work because the only change to your code comes after the grouping has been done, but it's the grouping that you need to change. You obviously don't want to group by the value in the `Name` column but rather the value in the `Name` column with " (POOL)" trimmed off the end of it, so you need code in the `GroupBy` argument that does that trimming.

Comment: That has indeed put me on the correct track.  Thank you.  (I'm VERY new to LINQ)
I just moved the split method to the field in Groupby, and it works.
If you put your comment as an answer, I can mark it as answered.
Many thanks.

Comment: I'm happy for you to post your poem answer with a specific solution rather than my general advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for  jmcilhinney in the comments I managed to solve my issue.

```
Private Function PoolComputerNames() As String
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim ret As String = $"[count] possible duplicate Computer Names found in Table Computer.{vbCrLf}"
    Dim computerTable As DataTable
    computerTable = ComputerTableAdapter.GetData
    Dim duplicates = computerTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("Name").Split("("c)(0).Trim()) _
        .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key)
    For Each d In duplicates
        count += 1
        ret = $"{ret}{vbTab}{d}{vbCrLf}"
    Next
    ret = ret.Replace("[count]", $"{count}")
    Return ret
End Function
```